# Is it possible to change radio buttons to check box in Android?

Tags: android, radio-button, android-checkbox

Designing a quiz which consists of 10 questions. First 5 questions will be having radio buttons as options and the next 5 will be check boxes.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/questiontext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/opt1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/opt2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/opt3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/opt4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RadioGroup>
```

In the layout I have defined radio buttons.
When user clicks on Next,  I am replacing the questions and options which I have stored in an array.
Once I reach end of question 5, I need to somehow replace this with check boxes instead to moving to new activity. Can this be achieved?

Comment: use a different layout

Comment: Do u meany by having another XML layout file and setting the content view to be that name once we reach end of question 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearradio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/opt1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/opt2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/opt3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/opt4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearcheck"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:visibility="gone">

<!-- PUT CHECKBOXES HERE -->
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And if you reach question 5 set radio layout visibility to gone and check layout to visible.